# Magento 2 - Upload image file using inline edit

Tags: magento2, catalog, product-grid, inline-editor

I am using inline edit for product grid. Now i can edit product name and other field but i cant upload any image.

```
 <editor>
     <editorType>text</editorType>
 </editor>
```

That is creating input text field. What should i use for input file type?

Comment: DO you upload the image on inline edit (or) simply show the image during inline edit?

Comment: I want to upload image.